# Connection Pooling with knex but Idle Connections stay alive

Tags: node.js, next.js, connection-pooling, knex.js, vercel

I'm using knex w/ pg and the following configuration (trying to kill idle connection ASAP),
but the stay alive for very very long (more than minutes).

```
const knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    host: <myhost>,
    port: <myport>,
    user: <myuser>,
    password: <mypassword>,
    database: <mydb>,
  },
  pool: {
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 500,
    reapIntervalMillis: 500,
  },
});
```

I've added both configurations (`idleTimeoutMillis` - to have the connections be closed after 500ms, and `reapIntervalMillis` - to initiate a destruction process every 500ms). Neither configuration changes the fact that the idle connections stay alive for much much longer than that.

Any advice would be hugely appreaciated.

Comment: How do you know idle connections are actually idle and not used during 500ms to 1 second time window?